# Files explorer crashes on start up and windows have started looking odd

Tags: linux, ubuntu

So my ubuntu machine has started acting oddly. Things like the Files explorer crashes whenever I try to open it, and all the windows are started looking odd like the "close/minimize" icons in the corner are missing (but still work) and the terminal window is now white instead of black. Is there some auto-repair command that I can run to hopefully fix these issues?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed a theme? that would be the first place to look for odd appearance... however, that does not explain Files crashing.

There are [some simple repairs to the OS that can be performed from Termina](https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-broken-packages-ubuntu/)l.

- First, try fixing any *broken* packages:

> sudo dpkg --configure -a

- Then try to fix *missing* packages:

> ```
> sudo apt update --fix-missing
> sudo apt install -f
> ```

- If that has not fixed the issue, use [Synaptic Package Manager](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/synaptic-package-manager-beginners-guide-for-ubuntu-users.html). Sort the packages by *Status* and look for any problems.
- Finally, when all else fail, *save your files*, or, better, *make a disk image*, and then reinstall Ubuntu.